# List of integers with recurring odd numbers

Tags: python

Given a list of `0` to `N` sequential integers, where `N` is an even number, e.g. `A = [0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4]` I'm looking for a list comprehension, i.e. of type `[a for a in A]`, for creating another list `B = [0 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4]` that repeats the odd numbers in the input list, `A`.

Comment: That kind of expression is called a list comprehension, but I don't think it can do what you're asking for.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Try generators! (Hint: `yield` twice.)

Comment: @David I am more of a beginner at Python and I didn't know the name of the type of expression until Thomas K's response (thanks Tom). I can use an explicit for loop but I was wondering if its possible to generate the output list using a list comprehension.

Comment: @MartijnPieters don't assume the worst. Please refer to my previous comment. I am just getting to grips with Python and am amazed by how much that can be done in just one line.

Comment: @Olumide, Martijn is pointing out what most everyone on here deals with everyday: people being lazy.  I like what David posted about "What have you tried?" as it shows the potential responders what effort you have put in thus far (and what doesn't work).  Some answers are VERY lengthy and if you tried some techniques and it didn't work for you, you could potential end up wasting someones valuable time!  

On that note:  since you are new to Python I'd also recommend reading PEP 8 and PEP 20 if you haven't already.  I wish someone told me about those when I started out =/

Comment: Okay. I'll note the tradition from now on. Its just that in this case I hadn't the foggiest clue how to proceed with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a (somewhat ugly) solution with a list comprehension:

```
a = range(5)
list(itertools.chain(*[[x, x] if x % 2 == 1 else [x] for x in a]))
# => [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

The list comprehension builds a list of sublists:

```
[[x, x] if x % 2 == 1 else [x] for x in a] # => [[0], [1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [4]]
```

The `itertools.chain` call is just one of the many ways to [flatten a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) in Python.

Comment: I came up with something similar, but I couldn't figure out how to "collapse" the list. Rather, in order to output two values, I output it as an array (as you've done).

Comment: [Using `itertools.chain`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/815632) is a far more efficient way to chain together lists- concatenating lists becomes very inefficient with large values of N.

Comment: Hans. You give me something to aim at! :)

Comment: @David: Wow, 1000% faster on my end. Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: @HansEngel, I'm glad you're enlightened! =) One minor point, though - `itertools.chain` returns a generator, not a list (you might want to clarify this / use `list()` to convert).

Answer (score 1):

```
itertools.chain(*[[i] * (i % 2 + 1) for i in xrange(N + 1)])
```